# Why does my AUC keep decreasing on each fold?

Tags: cross-validation, python, random-forest, cart, scikit-learn

For some reason, the `sklearn` random forest keeps returning a smaller and smaller value for AUC when I use it for binary classification.

I'm using some data that I generated myself, and the labels are 'yes' or no' and they have been converted into `1` and `0`.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import cross_validation as skcv
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, roc_auc_score, roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, make_scorer
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import base

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

new_df['A']=[0.99, 0.88, 0.39, 0.98, 0.23, 0.54, 0.19, 0.97, 0.123, 0.34, 0.234, 0.46, 0.56, 0.27, 0.576, 0.16, 0.689]
new_df['B']=[0.01, 0.14, 0.78, 0.18, 0.29, 0.64, 0.24, 0.95, 0.23, 0.35, 0.45, 0.49, 0.59, 0.39, 0.578, 0.19, 0.78]
new_df['C']=[0.51, 0.64, 0.18, 0.68, 0.19, 0.98, 0.39, 0.89, 0.35, 0.45, 0.51, 0.52, 0.60, 0.34, 0.98, 0.35, 0.90]
new_df['y']=['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes','no','no','no','yes','yes','no','no','yes']

numerical_cols = []
for col in filter(lambda col: col!='y', new_df.columns):
    if not (new_df[col].dtype != 'int64' and new_df[col].dtype != 'float64'):
        numerical_cols = numerical_cols + [col]


feature_df = new_df.replace({'y':{'no':0, 'yes':1}})
num_feature_df = feature_df[numerical_cols+['y']]

num_feature_cols = filter(lambda col: col != 'y' , num_feature_df.columns)

for train_index, test_index in skcv.KFold(len(num_feature_df), n_folds = 3):
    rf = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(
            random_state = 10,
            oob_score = True,
            n_estimators = 200,
            min_samples_leaf = 3,      
            max_depth = 3)             


    rf.fit(num_feature_df.iloc[train_index][num_feature_cols], num_feature_df.iloc[train_index]['y'])
    _scores = rf.predict_proba(num_feature_df.iloc[test_index][num_feature_cols])[:,1]
    auc = roc_auc_score(num_feature_df.iloc[test_index]['y'], _scores, average='macro', sample_weight=None)
    print auc
```

The AUC consistently decreases after each fold in the k-folds.  It doesn't matter how many folds, and it doesn't matter the hyper-parameters for the random forest, and even if the data is a little bit different it doesn't matter - the AUC consistently decreases at each iteration.

Why is the AUC consistently decreasing after each fold in k-folds cross validation?

Comment: I'd be happy to answer any other clarifying questions about this.....it seems to be an issue with `sklearn` because I can't reproduce in `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may happen when there is some pattern in the order of data. For example, if your data is time ordered, then some pattern  could exist in one fold and have less strong presence in others. This can decrease the evaluation measure.

There are several solutions for this. First, you can get rid of this by shuffling you dataset before splitting - and, quite likely, this is what happens in R.

Another approach would be reconsidering the way you cross validate. If there's time, then it makes sense to use it when splitting the data.

Comment: so, you're telling me that `sklearn` doesn't automatically shuffle the indices when constructing the folds?

Comment: There really doesn't seem to be a pattern in the order of the `synthetic data` that I generated above, unless you can find one?

Comment: Yes it doesn't: by default `shuffle=False`. While there may not seem to be a pattern, apparently RF finds one.

Comment: I keep shuffling the data and somehow RF keeps finding a pattern?  I think there's a deeper issue here....maybe with `sklearn`'s RF or something